# Floating-point precision when dealing with trigonometric functions

Tags: java, precision, trigonometry

I have a Java class that deals with a lot of trigonometric functions using `java.lang.Math`. The following code determines the average direction of 0 degrees and 180 degrees. The result should be NaN, since 0 degrees and 180 degrees are in opposite directions, canceling each other out. However, when I do:

```
double[] angles = {0, 180};
double sines = 0;
double cosines = 0;
double avg;
for (int i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {
    double rad = Math.toRadians(angles[i]);
    sines += Math.sin(rad);
    cosines += Math.cos(rad);
}
double sin = sines / angles.length;
double cos = cosines / angles.length;
System.out.println("Avg sin: " + sin + "\nAvg cos: " + cos); // sin != 0 but it should
double avgRad = Math.atan2(sin, cos);
avg = Math.toDegrees(avgRad);
System.out.println("Average: " + avg);
```

`avg` equals `90.0` instead of `NaN`. This is because the average sine of 180 degrees and 0 degrees results in a very small but positive number (due to the way floating-point precision works). If you run the above code you will see what I mean. How can I avoid this lack of precision? I know that I could round the average sines and cosines as well as the final result, but that seems a little inelegant to me.

Comment: Floating point math is susceptible to rounding errors. Live with it.

Comment: I know that it is. I'm asking how to circumvent it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am determining the average direction of an array of directions (in terms of degrees). The above code returns an incorrect result when the array is [0, 180] because of how floating-point precision works. I am trying to circumvent this issue. (I mention that I could round some of the values, but that seems inelegant, and I could lose precision with all that rounding.)

Comment: Presumably, you have some reason for summing the sines and cosines. You're asking for trouble by using atan(). Use atan2() instead.

Comment: What do you take average of 0,180 as? Also 0,360 as? Don't you want the average of 0,180 as 90? Don't you want the average of 0,360 as 0?

Answer (score 0):

I take it granted that you must have considered averaging angles directly (by using mod 360) before you went onto use sin/cos/tan. That being said, I think, you are in right direction in getting what you intended in your code (except possibly the negative sign flip in the last example).

```
~> java Main 0 180
Avg sin: 6.123233995736766E-17
Avg cos: 0.0
Average: 90.0

~> java Main 0 179
Avg sin: 0.00872620321864172
Avg cos: 7.615242180436521E-5
Average: 89.50000000000011

~> java Main 1 179
Avg sin: 0.017452406437283477
Avg cos: 0.0
Average: 90.0

~> java Main 1 180
Avg sin: 0.008726203218641817
Avg cos: -7.615242180436521E-5
Average: 90.49999999999991

~> java Main 1 181
Avg sin: 1.5959455978986625E-16
Avg cos: 0.0
Average: 90.0

~> java Main 1 182
Avg sin: -0.008723545132608694
Avg cos: 2.2843406864775373E-4
Average: -88.50000000000001
```